# Zero account in profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I don't see anymore my accounts in my profile...

[image: screenshot]

I'm on Programmers, Area 51 etc.. on every site I have 0 account in profile...

Comment: Nice 0 accountS :p

Comment: They are most likely [running a backfill](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes#comment332126_124203) to account for the recent global reputation recalc. They'll be back soon.

Comment: (or general aggregator maintenance, though there's a slight bug in so much as the local tab should mention that the information is temporarily unavailable, like the network profiles currently do)

Comment: Are you sure you exist?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was running a backfill on our network aggregation service to account for a minor service outage we had earlier last week.

This revealed a bug in our "temporarily unavailable" messaging, caused by transitioning the accounts tab onto the public API.

Accounts should be available again now (some caching may be in play for some users, but everything should be back to normal soon-ish), and the next deploy should fix the underlying bug.

Answer (score 14):

There are no accounts anymore.  Meta's been a bit too uppity the past few days and we decided to end the network, sorry!

Comment: And thus, Experts Exchange wins.

Comment: I knew I should have provided a distraction by posting a comical and pedantic bug report before things got out of hand. My bad, everyone.

Comment: :'-( No! Admit it, it's too made us go more often on the bottom of the page!

Comment: @AnthonyPegram [Subscribe now for full access* and get
INSTANT ACCESS to this comment!] *30 Day FREE access, no risk, no obligation...